# How to implement a facebook like feed with comments and likes in SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, web-part, list, newsfeed

I require a web part in which feeds can be posted and users can comment and like on it.

Answer (score 2):

With 2010 you would either have to build it or buy the suite from Newsgator.  Realistically though it would be more cost effective to upgrade to 2013 or implement Yammer.